# Why are results from `top` in batch mode different than from interactive `top`?

Tags: linux, command-line, top

When I run

```
top -b -n1 -o +%CPU
```

my `asterisk` rarely appears as one of the top processes and the `top` is usually the first. But when I run `top` interactively `asterisk` is usually number 1.

Why is that? Is there a difference in batch and interactive setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `top` works in bursts

> the `top` is usually the first

Run `time top -b -n1 -o +%CPU`. You will see it takes little time (e.g. 0.2 s) during which the tool is relatively busy. If you use `-b -n2` then you will see the difference between the first and the second iteration. Any iteration but the first spends most time doing almost nothing until the update interval (e.g. 3 s) passes.

Interactive `top` works similarly. You probably haven't noticed the very first iteration shows `top` with higher `%CPU` value than later iterations do.

And if you run `top -b -n2 -d0 -o +%CPU` then the second iteration will show you `top` with very high `%CPU` value. The same for interactive `top -d0`. Here `top` doesn't wait by itself and therefore it's maximally busy.

Your question arose because all iterations but the first depend on the delay interval (specified by `-d` or in `~/.toprc`, or the default one). For steady processes other than the `top` itself it may not matter. For `top` it's different because the tool needs to do basically the same amount of work per iteration, no matter how long the iteration takes. It's one burst per iteration. The longer the iteration takes, the lower `%CPU` you get for `top`. A lower value reflects the same amount of work averaged over longer time.

You should compare first iterations from separate runs; or non-first iterations from the same run or from separate runs where the interval is the same.

If you want to get one non-interactive iteration that does depend on the specified interval, use `-b -n2` and discard the first iteration.

---

#### `asterisk` may work in bursts

> `asterisk` rarely appears as one of the top processes […]. But when you run `top` interactively, `asterisk` is usually number 1.

I admit I haven't tested with actual `asterisk`. It deals with packets of data, so it's possible it may work in bursts. I don't mean it's totally idle in between for sure, I mean there may be peaks in CPU usage by `asterisk`.

In general consider `asterisk` as an example program. What can happen when there are peaks in CPU usage?

The first iteration of `top` may or may not catch a peak. So `%CPU` for `asterisk` may be substantially greater or lower than `%CPU` for other (possibly steady) processes. In effect sometimes `asterisk` is number 1, usually not. A non-first iteration will show you average values for `%CPU`. The peaks may be not-so-frequent, so in the first iteration of `top` "`asterisk` rarely appears as one of the top processes"; but they may be high enough to boost the average `%CPU` for `asterisk`, so non-first iterations show that "`asterisk` is usually number 1".

---

#### Other processes may work in bursts

I don't know if it happens in your case but it's certainly possible.

Imagine several processes different than `asterisk` in question, so each of them stresses CPU from time to time, only for a moment; otherwise they are mostly idle. Imagine that almost each run of `top -b -n1 +%CPU` happens where two or three of them dominate over `asterisk` (regardless if `asterisk` actually works in bursts or with peaks, or steadily). They dominate not because you are lucky to catch them when they burst, but because of probability that favors this scenario if the number of such processes is big enough. I mean if there are many such processes then you have to be lucky not to catch any of them burst. Imagine the set of dominating processes is different each time; it's not the same set that could dominate the average CPU usage. Such processes may die and new processes may be spawned.

Then it's totally possible `asterisk` is rarely number 1 in terms of "momentary" `%CPU` and it's always number 1 in terms of average `%CPU`.

---

#### Summary

When you write about non-interactive `top`, you consider the first (in case of `-n1`: the only) iteration of each run. This happens relatively fast and promotes processes (including the `top` itself) with high CPU usage *at the moment*.

When you write about interactive `top`, you apparently mean non-first iterations. They depend on the delay interval which by default is substantially greater than the time any first iteration takes. In effect they promote processes with high *average* CPU usage.